# Xpath Query to match immediate sibling nodes in a sequence

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathquery

I'm new to XPATH and I'd like to know if there is a nice way to do this using XPATH queries.

I want to match consecutive sibling nodes in a XML tree to certain predefined rules for example if there are three sibling nodes occurring immediately one after the other and they have the attributes value="A", value="B" and value="C", I want the XPATH query to match the first node/last node in such a sequence and I want to extract all such consecutive sequence of nodes from the XML tree so that I can process them later on.

Thanks!

Comment: Some illustrative example XML would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is one possible solution**:

First:

> I want to match consecutive sibling
>   nodes in a XML tree to certain
>   predefined rules for example if there
>   are three sibling nodes occurring
>   immediately one after the other and
>   they have the attributes value="A",
>   value="B" and value="C",

```
//*[@value='A' 
  and 
   following-sibling::*[1]/@value='B' 
  and 
   following-sibling::*[2]/@value='C']
```

Then:

> I want to extract all such consecutive
>   sequence of nodes from the XML tree
>   ...

```
    //*[@value='A' 
      and 
       following-sibling::*[1]/@value='B' 
      and 
       following-sibling::*[2]/@value='C']
   |
    //*[@value='A' 
      and 
       following-sibling::*[1]/@value='B' 
      and 
       following-sibling::*[2]/@value='C']

      /following-sibling::*[position() = 1 or position()=2]
```

Here is how the selection looks like in the true XPathVisualizer (_http://www.topxml.com/xpathvisualizer/ -- this link has a trojan -- click only if you have good malware protection. Alternatively, contact me for the app.):

[image]

Finally:

> I want the XPATH query to match the
>   first node/last node in such a
>   sequence

```
    //*[@value='A' 
      and 
       following-sibling::*[1]/@value='B' 
      and 
       following-sibling::*[2]/@value='C']
   |
    //*[@value='A' 
      and 
       following-sibling::*[1]/@value='B' 
      and 
       following-sibling::*[2]/@value='C']

      /following-sibling::*[position()=2]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This doesn't answer the question.  I misunderstood it when writing this.**

To query them, 
use `position()=1 or position()=last()` as a predicate, possibly along with other predicates you use to select the nodes.

This is what it looks like in [XpathVisualizer](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=xpathvisualizer):

[image]

"Extracting them" is not a matter for xpath.  For that you can enumerate the selected elements and then do whatever you like, it's up to you.